# How to estimate $\int^{1}_{-1} \left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)^{300} dx$ to 1 significant figure?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, approximation

I would like to estimate $\int^{1}_{-1} \left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)^{300} dx$ to $1$ significant figure. (This question is taken from a quant exam).

My (vague) idea is to use Taylor series expansion and to estimate the remainder term. But then I run into problems immediately as I don't see a straightforward way to compute the first few terms of Taylor series for $\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)^{300}$...

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean -1? In any case you can use the Laplace method, after rewriting $(\sin(x)/x)^{300}=e^{300 \log(\sin(x)/x))}$.

Comment: Yes, I just corrected it @Ian

Comment: Thanks - I totally forgot about Laplace method! @Ian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approximation by exponential**

Approximating $\frac{\sin(x)}x\approx1-\frac{x^2}6$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{\sin(x)}x\right)^{300}\,\mathrm{d}x
&\approx\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{300}6x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{10}\\[9pt]
&=0.25066
\end{align}
$$
where we can compute $\sqrt{2\pi}$ by hand using $\pi=3.1416$ and the scaffold method for square roots:
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{2\pi}
&=\sqrt{6.2832}\\
&=2\sqrt{1.5708}\\
&=2(1.2533)\\
&=2.5066
\end{align}
$$

For comparison, the original integral is approximately $0.250537$.

---

**Contour Integration**

There are no singularities so we can offset the contour by $-i$.
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{\sin(x)}x\right)^{300}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1{2^{300}}\int_{-\infty-i}^{\infty-i}\frac{\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)^{300}}{x^{300}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{2^{300}}\sum_{k=0}^{149}\int_{\gamma^+}(-1)^k\binom{300}{k}\frac{e^{i(300-2k)x}}{x^{300}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&+\cancel{\frac1{2^{300}}\sum_{k=151}^{300}\int_{\gamma^-}(-1)^k\binom{300}{k}\frac{e^{i(300-2k)x}}{x^{300}}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=\frac{2\pi i}{2^{300}}\sum_{k=0}^{149}(-1)^k\binom{300}{k}\frac{-i(300-2k)^{299}}{299!}\\
&=\frac\pi{299!}\sum_{k=0}^{149}(-1)^k\binom{300}{k}(150-k)^{299}\\[9pt]
&=0.25053746380056856955
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\gamma^+=[-R-i,R-i]\cup Re^{i[0,\pi]}-i
$$
and
$$
\gamma^-=[-R-i,R-i]\cup Re^{-i[0,\pi]}-i
$$
Note that $\gamma^-$ does not contain the origin.

Comment: Hmm... I thought the original question had an exponent of $100$.  I see that it was $300$. I guess it is clear enough how to adjust my answers to work. If desired, I can fix my answers.

Comment: *Amazing !* was my first reaction when reading your answer. The next and final one is *Beautiful !*. Many thanks for providing us so elegant solutions. Cheers.

Comment: I have adjusted the exponent to $300$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks! However, my first approach is just a simplification of Zhuoran He's answer. For such a large exponent, $\left(1-\frac{x^2}6\right)^{300}=e^{-50x^2}$ is pretty good. By the time the $5x^4/3$ term becomes big enough to matter, $e^{-50x^2}$ is very small.

Comment: I was mainly speaking about the contour Integration : this is very elegant.

Answer (score 10):

The saddle point approximation for
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sin^{n}x}{x^{n}}dx&=\int_{-1}^1 e^{n\ln\frac{\sin x}{x}}dx=\int_{-1}^1e^{-n(\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{180}+\frac{x^6}{2835}+\cdots)}dx\\
&\approx\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{n}{6}x^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{6\pi}{n}},\quad n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
It does not matter whether $n$ is even or odd, because $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is even and the negative parts haven't been reached by the integration bounds yet, or even if they are reached, they become too small in the $n\rightarrow\infty$ limit.

Answer (score 4):

More than inspired by Zhuoran He's answer and assuming that we could require more accuracy
$$I_n=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sin^{n}x}{x^{n}}\,dx\approx \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{n}{6}x^2-\frac{n}{180}x^4}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{15}{2}} e^{5 n/8} K_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{5 n}{8}\right)$$ where appears the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Expanding for infinitely large values of $n$, we have
$$I_n\approx \sqrt{\frac{6\pi}{n}}-\frac{3}{10} \sqrt{\frac{3 \pi }{2n^3}}+\frac{21}{80} \sqrt{\frac{3 \pi }{2n^5}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{7/2}}\right)$$ which leads to more than acceptable results when compared to numerical integration
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 100 & 0.4335090102 & 0.4335152100 \\
 200 & 0.3067676765 & 0.3067687712 \\
 300 & 0.2505374649 & 0.2505378616 \\
 400 & 0.2169989558 & 0.2169991493 \\
 500 & 0.1941043334 & 0.1941044444 \\
 600 & 0.1772010667 & 0.1772011384 \\
 700 & 0.1640621723 & 0.1640622203 \\
 800 & 0.1534702230 & 0.1534702566 \\
 900 & 0.1446979461 & 0.1446961543 \\
 1000 & 0.1372730901 & 0.1372731089
\end{array}
\right)$$